# Mongoose - flexible field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to NOSQL and MongoDB, I am building an app with NodeJS and Mongoose, and I am building a mongoose schema for a new collection.

The documents of this collection will have some standard fields (id, creation date, user etc...) but then I need to store other stuff, which is a "data" field which will have to contain different data depending on the document. The value will sometimes be simple text and other times it will have lots of key/values pairs.

I am wondering what would be the best solution for this kind of storing needs :

-Create only one "data" field with a String type and then put different types of data into it (text for simple values, stringified objects for more complex data)

-Create in the model all the possible fields that my "more complex data" could have and use only the ones I need in each document

-Something else

What is the best practice for this kind of thing ?

Comment: I'd say use a schema-less type instead of stringified data. That said, some people will say that dynamic schemas is the strength of mongodb, some will say that it's unmaintainable and bad practice. I'll leave that discussion for others, but if you're going to use schema-less types, read [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) about some actual cons (such as no validation and lost ability to auto-detect changes).

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the Mixed schemaType, I think that's what you are looking for:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Answer (score 2):

This one:

> -Create in the model all the possible fields that my "more complex data" could have and use only the ones I need in each document

Mark the standard fields of the schema as `required: true` and leave the rest optional.  That way you get the flexibility you want without losing the Mongoose benefits of validation, casting, and change detection.